# How to configure Docker for Windows to accept a self-signed SSL?

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

My network at work is using SSL inspection and is resigning all SSL traffic with its own root CA certificate.  The enterprise CA root certificate is already installed in my Trusted Root Certification store.

However, when I try to pull an image using the docker client, I get the following error:

```
$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I'm using the latest version of Docker for Windows (Version 17.12.0-ce-win46 (15048)) on Windows 10.

How/where can I install the root certificate such that docker sees it?

Answer (score 3):

I add it via GUI, like this:
[image]

It's works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it according to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/). Add the following to `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["registry-1.docker.io"]
}
```

Comment: I had already tried that and it still gave me the same error message.  Additionally, this would also imply that I have to list each registry one at a time, whereas I would just like Docker to trust my root CA and not have to worry about it.

Comment: Docs suggest you may be able to change it through the settings dialog too. Tried that? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#docker-daemon

Comment: Actually - I had tried it via the settings GUI - not directly in the daemon.json file.  I'll try it in the daemon.json file tomorrow.

Comment: @EricB. did you got any solution?

Comment: @Arjun No; I never found a consistent solution, but worked around it by having the IT department to simply whitelist docker.io.

Answer (score 1):

Besides adding insecure-registries in the daemon.json/docker desktop settings, you should double click the self-CA to install them.
Attention：You need to save the CA in the trusted zone instead of a personal or  other untrust zone.